# How to generate a new URL for new content?

Tags: javascript, database

I'm trying to randomly generate a new URL (i.e. mydomain.com/XXXXX) for a users content.

Something similar to imgur.com or pastebin.com, where a user submits content, and then a randomly generated URL is created for that content.

If anyone can point me towards a solution (ideally in JavaScript), I would be very thankful.

Also, in order to make the generated pages available permanently, I assume that would require the use of a database?

Comment: Javascript is for frontend development, it can't do anything regarding URL generation. You are talking about NodeJS?

Comment: which is your server side script??

Comment: Apologies, wasn't very clear. Using NodeJS.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen — JavaScript is JavaScript no matter what host environment it is running in.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is done at the server end. There are several methods to do that.
One of the methods is the .htaccess file for apache servers.
You can create a .htaccess file and add the following code to it

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ content_generator.php?content_code=$1
    </IfModule>
```

Here you can point your pages to http://example.com/content/12effas the code **12effas** will be passed on to your server file content_generator.php in the request variable content_code. You can easily  serve the specific content for that code using your DB.